# PDO update fails with Ajax though POST vars are passed correctly

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Form submission and db update perform as desired when stand alone. When ajax is used, it submits the correct POST vars are passed but I end up with a PDO exception I don't understand how to fix because it works properly when not making the ajax post. **New to both PDO and Ajax.**

```
    <form id="privacy" action="privacy.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" value="<?php echo $user->id; ?>">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="name" class="name" value="private" />
            <img src="img/lock.png">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="name" class="name" value="friends"/>
            <img src="img/friends.png">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="name" class="name" value="fof"/>
            <img src="img/friends-of-friends.png">
        </label>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(function() {
        $("#privacy").change(function() {
            var name = $(".name:checked").val();
            var id = $(".id").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "privacy.php",  
                data: {"name":name, "id":id},  
                success: function() { 
                    alert("form submitted: "+ id +" name:" + name);
                    }
                });
             });
         });
    </script>
```

**Update Function**

```
    public function Privacy($id,$name)
{

        // Building INSERT QUERY
        $sql = "UPDATE user_privacy";

        // keep only wanted fields (change this) to 'field' => value
        $data = array_filter($_POST);

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $cols = array('id' => 'id','name' => 'name');

        $count = 0;
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if(array_key_exists($key, $cols) && $cols[$key] != 'id'){
                $sql .= ' SET ' . $cols[$key] . ' = :'. $cols[$key] . ' WHERE parent_id = :id';
                unset($data[$key]);
                $count = count($data);

            } else { 
                if($count !== 0){
                   $i++;
                   $sql .= " $key = '$value' ";
                   $sql .= $i == $count ? " " : " AND ";
                }

            }
        }
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam("id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':'.$key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
}

   and the exception
```

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'id = '1'' at line 1 in C:\xampp2\htdocs\platform\library\library.php:151
Stack trace:
0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\platform\library\library.php(151): PDO->prepare('UPDATE user_pri...')
1 C:\xampp2\htdocs\platform\privacy.php(24): DemoLib->Privacy('1', 'private', NULL)
2 {main}
  thrown in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\platform\library\library.php** on line **151**

So how can I have an error there, if it updates properly before I add the ajax post submit. I can see that ajax is passing the post data ('1','private',NULll). So confused!

Comment: Shouldn't the line `$query->bindParam(':'.$key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);` be inside the foreach?

Comment: You're adding `SET` and `WHERE` each time through the `FOREACH` loop. There should just be one `SET` at the beginning, one `WHERE` at the end, and commas between each assignment.

Comment: Try printing `$sql` and you'll see how wrong it is.

Comment: You're also using `$key` and `$value` after the loop is done. You need to use `bindValue()` inside the loop.

Comment: @S.Dev There is always only going to be one post var besides the post['id'] ... radio buttons. ;)

Comment: You can pass an associative array to `$query->execute()`, then you don't need to call `bindParam()` separately for each parameter.

Comment: @Barmar the code works UNTIL I add the ajax and being new I can not for the life of me seem to return the $sql to print it once I get to the ajax call... remember new at this....

Comment: Put `echo $sql;` in the PHP code. To see the output, go to the Network tab of Developer Tools in the browser, select the AJAX request, and look at the Response.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what the `foreach` loop is supposed to be doing. It looks like it's trying to put some columns in the `SET` clause and other columns into the `WHERE` clause, but the logic doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after days of working on it I finally figured it out. Still have no idea what the issue was, but this is now the working code. As stated before, there will always only be one other field besides the "id" field but the other field is dynamic... As I develop further skills I will definitely be modifying this further to clean it up and structure it properly.

```
    $(function() {
        $("#privacy").change(function() {
             var uname = $(".name:checked").val();
             var uid = $(".id").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "privacy.php",  
            data: {"name":uname, "uid":uid},  
            success: function() { 
                }
            });
       });
    });
```

And the processing....

```
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $sql = "UPDATE user_privacy";
        $data = array_filter($_POST);
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'uid'){  
                $field = $key;
                $fieldValue = $value;
                $sql .= ' SET '. $key.' = :'.$key;
            }
        }
        $sql .= ' WHERE parentid = :uid';

        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':'.$field, $fieldValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
```